# Keyboard remapping on Windows 10: How can I map a long-pressed Enter/Return key to a modifier key (e.g. Ctrl)?

Tags: keyboard, windows-10-desktop, remap

I'd like to remap a long-press of an Enter/Return key to Ctrl(right), while keeping a short-press as Return.

I spend a fair amount of time in the terminal, particularly in Emacs in a WSL2 Ubuntu environment. Using long-press enter as Ctrl(right) makes Emacs commands much more comfortable. On MacOS I've used [Karabiner Elements](https://karabiner-elements.pqrs.org/) to achieve this but have not found a way to do it on Windows.

I've used the Keyboard Manager tool from [Windows Powertoys](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/powertoys/keyboard-manager) to remap CapsLock to Ctrl(Left), but this tool doesn't have a mechanism to distinguish a long-press from a short-press.